# strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string when i am redirect to a controller in Yii

Tags: yii

I have an error when i am trying redirect to a controller in Yii.

```
strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

if(!$error)
{
   \Yii::app()->request->redirect(array('site/nch1'));
}else{
   \Yii::app()->request->redirect(array('document/result'));
}
```

UPDATE: I am want redirected page to controller/action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a string, not an array, try this:

```
if(!$error)
{
   \Yii::app()->request->redirect('site/nch1');
}else{
   \Yii::app()->request->redirect('document/result');
}
```

Comment: I am want redirected page to controller/action. Your solution redirected to current action. But thanks

Comment: @ArthurYakovlev see: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#redirect-detail -it only needs to be an array if you are passing GET parameters as well. 

The controller is site, the action is nch1... or the controller is document, the action is result.

Comment: I will need to be redirect to absolute route module. \Yii::app()->request->redirect('/site/nch1'); Please edit your answer and thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to redirect. The answer above gets them mixed up.

```
Yii::app()->request->redirect('/actual/url/path.html');
```

and

```
Yii::app()->controller->redirect(['controller/action']);
$this->redirect(['controller/action']);
```

The CHttpRequest method [only takes a url](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#redirect-detail) path. It will need to be a url which exists.

The CController method [will take an array](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#redirect-detail) and generate the url itself.

Depending on the context, you can sometimes call the CController redirect method using `$this->redirect($route);` for example when in a controller or view file.